# c# WebClient read dell web site reture "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Tags: c#

I want to read dell web site get my dell services code Suppor date.

The website is:
"https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/2ZVC143/overview"

My code is：

```
website = "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-UjhFRUFhVmxqd25Ua2VSOS93ZXFZQT090/overview";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(website));
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc23 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

But reture

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I try add

```
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

But, did not work, How to solve it?

Comment: Many websites seem to require information to identify the client making the request, in the form of the User-Agent header. Perhaps try that.

Comment: The websites are supposed to be accessed via browsers. Hence they have various mechanism to verify whether the requests are coming from the browsers. This is to avoid attack via server to server requests by bots. The mechanisms may include checking user agent, cookies, anti forgery tokens, access tokens, certificates, request headers etc. Unless you know what's is being used by the dell web site and find a way to replicate similar requests in C# code, you can not get access to the page you want.

Comment: The other way is to write an automation using browser driver (such as selenium) which will open the browser window, log into the Dell web site using your credentials and redirect to the specific URL and scrap the required details from the page using HTML parsing.

Comment: Try using one of their APIs. you may be able to get the info you want 
https://developer.dell.com/apis

Answer (score 0):

The website requires a "User-Agent" header. And it doesn't have too many restriction on what it is, other than mainly it not be blank.

```cs
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers [ "User-Agent" ] = "UserAgent";
```

Comment: I have added this line of code but the problem persists